# How do I fix black desktop after installing Gnome3?

Tags: gnome, 13.10, desktop-environments

I recently installed Gnome3 from following an OMGUbuntu link (http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/12/upgrade-gnome-3-10-ubuntu-13-10) and it broke my desktop. Now it's black, I can't access the icons, and I can't apply a wallpaper. It's just dead. I followed the uninstall instructions and even installed Ubuntu Tweak and emptied all the junk stuff. No luck. Any fix for this?

This happened to me in 13.04 and I ended up needing to completely reinstall everything and I'm really hoping I don't have to do this again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you know the answer already.  Working with computers can be a pain but you sometimes you gotta do things over and over again before you get the result you desire.  Computers are no different.